# java randomAccessFile write every thing with space between each character

Tags: java, file-io, io

I used this function to write a line in specific index :

```
 private void write_line(Student s,int index){
        try {
            Student_pool.seek(0);
           Student_pool.seek(index*(25*Integer.SIZE+4*Character.SIZE));
            Student_pool.writeChars(s.getId());
            Student_pool.writeChars(s.getHw().substring(0,2));
            Student_pool.writeChars(".");
            Student_pool.writeChars(s.getHw().substring(3,5));
            Student_pool.writeChars(s.getPrj().substring(0,2));
            Student_pool.writeChars(".");
            Student_pool.writeChars(s.getPrj().substring(3,5));
            Student_pool.writeChars(s.getMidtermExam().substring(0,2));
            Student_pool.writeChars(".");
            Student_pool.writeChars(s.getMidtermExam().substring(3,5));
            Student_pool.writeChars(s.getFinalExam().substring(0,2));
            Student_pool.writeChars(".");
            Student_pool.writeChars(s.getFinalExam().substring(3,5));
            Student_pool.writeChars("\n");
            Student_pool.getFD().sync();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Storagelmpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        }
```

But when I try to open the file the result is not correct and every character has a space after it.
The result looks like this:

```
 8 1 0 1 8 7 3 1 2 2 0 . 0 0 2 0 . 0 0 2 0 . 0 0 2 0 . 0 0 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 8 1 0 1 8 8 2 7 5 1 6 . 0 0 1 0 . 0 0 1 3 . 0 0 1 9 . 0 0
```

I think there is problem with my encoding and another problem with my seek operand.
But I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's behaving exactly as documented:

Docs for `writeChars`:

> Writes a string to the file as a sequence of characters. Each character is written to the data output stream as if by the writeChar method. The write starts at the current position of the file pointer.

Docs for `writeChar`:

> Writes a char to the file as a two-byte value, high byte first. The write starts at the current position of the file pointer.

Do you actually need `RandomAccessFile` at all? Any reason for not using a `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter` using whichever encoding you want? Is there any way you can avoid having to write data at arbitrary positions like this?

You *could* use `writeBytes` instead of `writeChars` - that will basically write *just ISO-8859-1 characters* - would that be good enough for you? It's not going to preserve non-ISO-8859-1 data though...

Comment: About my seek function, am I pass the correct operand ?(I have 25 integers and 4 characters each line )

Comment: @pooya: You *don't* have 4 characters per line - look at all the characters you're writing! It's also not at all clear that you're writing *any* integers. It only looks like characters to me...

Comment: At first they are integer.
Thank you so much.

Comment: @pooya: What do you mean by "at first they are integer"? You're not *writing* them as integers - do you see what I mean? You seem to be computing the value as if you'd written the integer values as *binary data*, not text.

Comment: I mean at first I print them as Integer then I forget to change my computation.

Comment: How to write down non-ISO-8859-1 characters correctly using RandomAccessFile then? Or is it not possible?

Comment: @Ellrohir: As per the last paragraph, you *could* use `writeBytes`. But it would silently fail for any characters which aren't present in ISO-8859-1. If you want other behavior, you'd need to specify what you mean by "correctly" but it's likely to involve converting the characters into "the bytes you want to write" and then writing those.